# A Network Flow Problem Involving Redefined Labeling

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

**Problem**

We consider a network with $m$ nodes and $n$ directed edges. Suppose we can apply labels $y_r \in \mathbb{R}, \ r=1,2,\cdots,m$ to the nodes in the such way that if there is an edge from $r$ to $s$ then $y_r\geq y_s$.

Prove the following: if there is **no** directed path from node $i$ to $j$, then there exists a labeling of the nodes that satisfies $y_r\geq y_s$(if there is arc from $r$ to $s$) and $y_i<y_j$

**What I Have Done**

When it comes to network flow problem, I find incident matrix $M$ quite useful and therefore I use $M$ to formulate $y_r\geq y_s$ as $M^Ty \geq 0$. At the same time, there is constraints for network flow problem $Mf=0$ where $f$ stands for flows on different arcs.

From $M^Ty\geq 0$ and $M^Ty=0$, I immediately think of Farkas' lemma, but this is how far I could get since I do not really know to proceed.

Could anyone help me, thank you in advance!

Comment: I would consider a different title. Farkas' lemma is your idea of a solution, _and it may indeed be right_, but that's not really what the problem is about.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Already done that and do you have any idea about proceeding my thought.